# javascript don't get controller array in production environment

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I have a VFP that read a web service to get positions, this positions send to js as array, in sandbox environment works well but when I make the implementation to production environment the arrays are null, do you have any workarround for this?

This is my code in the controller:

```
public transient List<Decimal> lats {get;set;}
public transient List<Decimal> lngs {get;set;}

public void getPositions(){
    for(Integer i=0; i<nPositions.size(); i++){
          system.debug('#### ' + nPositions.get(i));
          lats.add(Decimal.valueOf(nPositions.get(i).Latitud));
          lngs.add(Decimal.valueOf(nPositions.get(i).Longitud));
    }
}
```

This is the JS code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var lats = new Array();
    var lngs = new Array();
    function getP(){
        console.log('{!lats}');
        var latis = '{!lats}';
        var res = latis.substr(1,latis.length-2);
        lats = res.split(', ');

        console.log('{!lngs}');
        var lngis = '{!lngs}';
        var res = lngis.substr(1,lngis.length-2);
        lngs = res.split(', ');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Angello - it's going to be virtually impossible to answer this question without specifics. Can you start with a code example showing how you obtain and utilize this data, and show us how you've tried to debug it?

Comment: Hi @DavidReed, thanks for you reply, I just added the code, as I said this is working in sandbox, but is not working in production

Comment: `transient` means that the values are cleared/removed from the view state. If you do not call `getPositions` during *every single action*, and the script is rerendered, this would be one possible cause. You're going to need to more debugging and/or add more code from both your page and controller here. There's simply too many variables here.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, thanks for you reply, I understand but as I said this is working in sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

Tentatively, I think the following adjustments should work.

## Use Separate Getters

Since you're trying to use transient lists, some simple getters would work better. In Visualforce, a function named `getX` can be merged directly into the page via the merge field `{!X}` (i.e. the merge field looks for a function with `get` prepended to the merge field).

## Direct Script Injection

Also, you don't need to parse the values directly, as you can safely insert the code directly into the script. Note that this is **only** safe for types like Boolean and Decimal, while String should be encoded and parsed for safety. See following example:

```
var firstName = "{!JSENCODE(Contact.FirstName)}"; // make the value safe.
```

---

Applying the above concepts, here's a possible alternative to your original code.

## Apex

```
public Decimal[] getLats() {
  Decimal[] values = new Decimal[0];
  // change nPosition to correct data type
  for(nPosition position: nPositions) {
    values.add(position.Latitud);
  }
  return values;
}
public Decimal[] getLngs() {
  Decimal[] values = new Decimal[0];
  // change nPosition to correct data type
  for(nPosition position: nPositions) {
    values.add(position.Longitud);
  }
  return values;
}
```

## JavaScript

```
var lats = {!lats};
var lngs = {!lngs};
```